# Why does my background go crazy or black after returning from suspend?

Tags: nvidia, suspend, desktop-background

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 and I've noticed that my background and/or lockscreen background goes either black or *very colourful crazy* after returning from suspend. Any ideas why does it occur?

Sometimes desktop background goes fine after changing the background image but once I go suspend and return again, it goes either black or colourful.

I have GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2 on Asus FX502V laptop.
I'm using nvidia-driver-418 tested proprietary driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a known bug that's work in progress for Ubuntu 19.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1809407

The bug was fixed for Ubuntu 19.10 (released today).

Comment: Yisss thank you! Silly me didn't find the answer because I was looking for 'background' instead of 'wallpaper' :(